# Show that two framed links with same linking matrix are framed cobordant in $\mathbb{S}^3$

Tags: geometric-topology, knot-theory

Consider two framed links in $\mathbb{S}^3$ with the same linking matrix. Then they are framed-cobordant in $\mathbb{S}^3$ .

I would like to hear a proof of this fact or to know a book reference where i can read it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Expanding to the world of framed labeled links (each label gets a column of the linking matrix, multiple components can have the same label) I think the idea is that you can use a Seifert surface for a component to create a framed cobordism to a link where that component is replaced by a collection of meridians of other components, each with the same label and with a random framing. Do this to every component in order, and you're left with unknots for the first label, on which are meridian unknots of the second label, on which ... . Then you can merge & cancel meridians and normalize framings.